# jQuery select2 add class to selected items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to be able to add a class to selected tags so that I can style them different colours. Is there a way to do this? As an example see the following:

[image]

So if I wanted any category tags to be green, any location tags to be blue and any keyword tags to be red how would I do it. I have tried using the `templateSelection` option like so:

```
$('select').select2({
    templateSelection: function(item)
    {
        return '<span class="green">' + item.text + '</span>';
    }
});
```

But the HTML gets escaped so it shows the actual characters instead. Plus this wouldn't add the class to the tag itself anyway.

Comment: Can you not use css? `.location { background-color: #00F; }`

Comment: I could if they had the class location on them. That's what I'm asking, how would I apply a class to these items so I can then style them.

Comment: Just use select event.

Comment: Use jquery to add the class `$('data').addClass('location')`

Comment: @geoffs3310 my answer solves your problem. Please, try it and accept the answer as correct ;) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that `templateSelection` and then search if it's a location or a keyword, and **add `escapeMarkup`** property:

```
function template(data, container) {
  if(/Location\:/.test(data.text)) {
     return '<span class="location">'+data.text+'</span>';
  } else {
     return data.text;
  }
}

$('select').select2({
  templateSelection: template,
  escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; }
});
```

Please, see it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/cz4ofkvg/1/

Comment: Would he not have to call `template($(this))`?

Comment: Attributes will passed by refference, not neccesary override them

Comment: *"I have tried using the templateSelection option ... but the HTML gets escaped so it shows the actual characters instead."*

Comment: Edited just now ;) @dfsq

Comment: with `escapeMarkup` it's much better :)

Comment: The only problem I see is `/Location\:/.test(data.text)` not reliable. It will simply break if option text changes. I suggest `'<span class="' + $(data.element).data('class') + '">' + data.text + '</span>'`. Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/qicpwfbpyxEvI1TZ46kR?p=info

Comment: I only answer with the details that OP give us. Your solution is fine too, just in case OP can change the markup. However is a great improvement

Comment: can i add class to `select2-selection__rendered` or replace it?